# howto perform action by dragging file to icon?

Tags: windows-xp, pdf

I would like to split pdf files by dragging the file to an icon in the desktop.
There is a program line called pdftk that seems to have an option to split pdf files.
The syntax seems to be

```
pdftk <input_files> burst
```

is there a way that I can create an icon on the desktop that would perform this action?

I tried creating a shortcut to pdftk but dragging a file there does not do anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `.bat` file with the following contents:

```
@echo off
start pdftk %1 burst
```

If you drag & drop a file onto that script, it should do what you want.
You just have to make sure, that `pdftk` is available in the execution context (like by modifying the `PATH` environment variable).